# YII - perform controller action on session expire

Tags: php, session, yii

I am trying to update one column in DB during user session timeout,
I have been set the timeout in main.php,

```
'components' => array(  
    'session'=>array(

    'class'=>'CDbHttpSession',
    'timeout'=>10,
    )),
```

Now the application gets logout automatically after 10 seconds of inactivity,
how can i perform some controller action on default Yii session time-out  method (which class or method that performs default session expiry in Yii) ?

Comment: Please check this link and read beforeAction()  function:- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12124-how-to-implement-session-timeout/

Comment: This will be useful for application is inactive for 10 seconds but i need to do this action when browser tab is closed before 10 seconds ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `onSessionTimeout` method. The only thing you can do it so check whether the session has expired on the next action of the user and then do something.

Comment: To be precise, logout doesn't _happen_ in 10 seconds. If in more than 10 seconds you make any request, then in this request the application knows session has expired. Just add your own check whenever it is appropriate.